# How to deploy Create React App to Hostinger?

Tags: hosting, create-react-app, web-hosting

Im having a problem viewing the subpages of my website that i deployed to Hostinger root folder or equivalent(subdomain), I run "npm run build" and deploy the files inside "build" folder to hostinger.

Of course it works on my local and firebase, but not on Hostinger.

See the files below for home, inner pages and FTP content.

**home:**

[image]

**subpages:**

[image]

**ftp content from "build" folder.**

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this here are the steps:

1. Create .htaccess inside your 'public' folder and paste the ff code.

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

2. Build the app using the command below.

   npm run build OR yarn build
3. And deploy your 'build' folder to your root folder or equivalent(subdomains).

That's it, It works to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Build on Your local computer

   npm run build
2. upload only build folder on hostinger

   all the files inside build must be moved to the public_html folder
   and delete the build folder ( as it is blank now )
3. Congrats your React Site is Live

   Yes, you don't need any commands & configurations.